# How could I replicate this this collar

Tags: texturing

How could I create this collar with the rigged effect? Is it something as simple as extruding faces on the jacket? Or is it more complicated with nodes? [image]

Comment: I'm sure you could do it both ways. I personally would just extrude the mesh at intervals but that's because I'm not super good with materials yet. I think a professional would do it with materials to keep the geometry simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use normals to fake the stripes:

Create a plane, subdivide it, bump it, create a second plane to bake the first one:

[image]

[image]

Use the normal map to fake the stripes:

[image]